# (resove an differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am having difficulties in finding the solution $v(z,\tau)$ of the following problem

$$\displaystyle \partial_z v( \partial_{\tau} v - \partial^2_z v) 
- v \partial_z (\partial_{\tau} v - \partial^2_z v)=0$$

Can any one help me please.

Comment: You might notice that this looks very similar to the quotient rule $$\left( \frac{f}{g} \right)' = \frac{f' g - f g'}{g^{2}}$$ so see if you can put your equation in that form.

Comment: yes it is. And then? How we can find $v$ with this method please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using separation of variables $v(z,\tau) = T(\tau)Z(z)$, one gets

$$Z'(T'Z-TZ'')-Z(T'Z'-TZ''') = 0 \implies -\frac{Z''}{Z} + \frac{Z'''}{Z'} = 0$$

or $$Z'Z'' = ZZ'''$$

Then guess that $Z(z) = e^{f(z)}$ and solve the resulting differential equation. Notice that $T$ doesn't actually matter, it could be any $\mathcal{C}^1$ function.

Comment: please who is $f(z)$?

Comment: @mati you can do that on your own

Comment: I try this: $$  Z(z)=e^{f(z)} $$ then $Z'= f'(z) e^{f(z)}, Z''= f''(z) e^{f(z)}, Z'''= f'''(z) e^{f(z)}$. Then the equality $Z' Z'' = Z Z''$ implies that $$ (f'(z))^4 e^{2 f(z)}= (f'(z))^3 e^{2 f(z)} ,$$ wich implies that $$ (f'(z)) e^{2 f(z)} = e^{2 f(z))}$$ then we have $f'(z)=1$. Then we deduce that $f(z)=z$. So we can choose $T(\tau)= \tau$? Then $$v(\tau,z)= \tau z$$. is it correct? Please.